# How to check out a document from a remote sharepoint server programatically (c#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, checkout

I did a quite lot of research on how I could do this, but did not found the solution...
My use case is the following:
there are some excel sheets on our corporate intranet (SharePoint); my software needs to check them out, open them, edit, and check back again (from a client machine). I can access the files via unc path (\server\whatever.xls). As a workoround now I can copy them to the local machine, do de editing, save them, but since they were not checked out, I can not upload them again.

Is there any way to do this?

As I red it the SPFile.CheckOut should do the trick, but I did not find any information about how to find the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll...

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Comment: You need to have SharePoint installed on your machine to be able to use Microsoft.SharePoint.dll. Also try to find out how to use SharePoint client object model to check out files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you are running your code on a machine where SharePoint is not hosted. And you wish to checkout the file(s) remotely. In that case, use the ListService form SharePoint to do this.

Here is a small example:

```
Web_Reference_Folder.Lists listService = new Web_Reference_Folder.Lists();
listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
string fileCheckout = "http://Server_Name/sites/Subsite/Shared Documents/MyFile.txt";
bool myResults = listService.CheckOutFile(fileCheckout, "true", "20 Jun 2006 12:00:00 GMT");
```

You can see all the services of SharePoint here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28v=office.12%29.aspx

In case you are running the code on the machine, where SharePoint is installed, in that case you can add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll and proceed. If you wish to deploy your code onto a machine that will also host the SharePoint server, you need to compile the code also in a similar environment.

Comment: Can't you just open a SPSite with a non-local URL?

Comment: @bzlm: Could not comprehend your concern.

Comment: I'm just talking about the [SharePoint Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(office.14).aspx#SP2010ClientOM_Creating_Windows_Console_Application).

Comment: Yes, that is the case, SP is hosted hosted on a different machine. This will work I think, but what/where is Web_Reference_Folder?